# Split an array of binary search into unequal parts

Tags: algorithm, formula

In original iterative version of binary search in the sorted array we calculate the midpoint as follow:
`m = (i+j)/2` *(Take the floor of it)*

But, what if we decide to split it into unequal parts like 1/3 and 2/3 we use this formula :
`m = (2i+j)/3` *(Take the floor of it)*

So, I want your help with formula to split it into (1/4 and 3/4) , (1/5 and 4/5) or (2/5 and 3/5).
I just need the value of `m`, **not** the whole code.

FYI, `m = 3i+j/4` *(Is it not correct to split array into 1/4 and 3/4 ?)*

Comment: What are `i` and `j`?

Comment: Java and C are two very different programming languages.  Please pick one or the other!  Additionally, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I don't understand the question. It might be relevant to only calculate the size of one part of the array by the formula, and get the size of the other part by subtraction from the whole, not from the formula.

Comment: unclear what you are asking and how this relates to arrays

Comment: Java and C? Are we supposed to pick one?

Comment: What does 'we take the grounding of it' mean?

Comment: @phflack i=1 and j is the size of the array

Comment: @Bimde if you have 4.4 and the grounding of is 4

Comment: @markshancock I edited the post ,, Hope you get it now !

Comment: This seems to be more of an algorithm question than an actual SW question

Comment: @markshancock it's a pseudo code and yeah it's more algorithm question

Comment: @WeatherVane  I've just edited the post ,, Hope it's clear to you now !

Comment: Wouldn't the midpoint of a j length array be j/2 and not (1+j)/2?  If you're trying to split into 1/n, just divide the length by n

Comment: @phflack might want the larger part of an odd length array first. Perhaps `(j+n-1) / n`

Comment: @phflack I'm sure about the midpoint formula , m = 1/2(i+j)

Comment: @k3vin Array [0, 1, 2], j(length) = 3, i = 1, midpoint should be 1, m = (i + j)/2 = (1 + 3)/2 = 4/2 = 2.  1 != 2

Answer (score 0):

Let's do some maths:

**Assumptions:**

1. `i` is the lower index of an array,
2. `j` is the higher index of an array,
3. `m` is the partitioned index of an array, got by partitioning the array in `x:y` ratio.

See, the evaluation below:

```
<------x-----><----------y------------->
.-------------.------------------------.
^             ^                        ^
i             m                        j

therefore, it can be represented as 
      (m-i)/(j-m)   =   x/y
   =>     y.(m-i)   =   x.(j-m)
   =>   y.m - y.i   =   x.j - x.m
   =>   y.m + x.m   =   x.j + y.i
   =>     (x+y).m   =   x.j + y.i
   =>           m   =   (x.j + y.i)/(x+y)   (this is the final result)
```

**CASE 1:**  (1/4 and 3/4)  or can be written as `1:3`.

```
    m   =   (x.j + y.i)/(x+y)
=>  m   =   (1.j + 3.i)/(1+3)
=>  m   =   (j + 3.i)/4
```

**CASE 2:**  (1/5 and 4/5)  or can be written as `1:4`.

```
    m   =   (x.j + y.i)/(x+y)
=>  m   =   (1.j + 4.i)/(1+4)
=>  m   =   (j + 4.i)/5
```

**CASE 3:**  (2/5 and 3/5)  or can be written as `2:3`.

```
    m   =   (x.j + y.i)/(x+y)
=>  m   =   (2.j + 3.i)/(2+3)
=>  m   =   (2.j + 3.i)/5
```